# Full copy of datatable's row

Tags: datatable, copy, row

I need to copy a row in a datatable with it's child row. Do I have to iterate every child table or is there a faster way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: i make an example:
-row of DataTable "ParentTable" (with primary key "keyField")
   -row DataTable "ChildTable" (with foreign key "keyField")

I need a copy of this block, i need to change the primary key (and so the foreign key by constraints), then delete the original row, but doing this, i loose also the row of "ChildTable"

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "child row".  Can you clarify your question please?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could use JOIN,LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN to get all the results you want in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0):

You can get get it from the query result which you use to build the datatable or using `fnGetData`.

```
$('#yourTable').dataTable().fnGetData(rowNumber);
```

You can see the [reference](http://www.datatables.net/api) for more datails.